# Using params in flux queries with Python influxdb_client

Tags: python, sql-injection, influxdb, influxdb-python, flux-influxdb

I am trying to update all of our influxdb python queries, so that they are not vulnerable to sql injections.

To do this, I have read that you can use params with the `query_api()` and specifically with the `query_data_frame()` (https://medium.com/sekoia-io-blog/avoiding-injections-with-influxdb-bind-parameters-50f67e379abb)

The issue I am running into is that I can not figure out how to get my params to be passed into my queries. Below is an example of one of our queries:

```py
client = InfluxDBClient(url="localhost:5000", token="", timeout=100000, retries=0, enable_gzip=True, profilers="query, operator")
query_api = client.query_api()

ver = "data" # This variable would actually come from a function
params = {
    "ver": ver,
}
query =                      '''from(bucket: "db")
                                |> range(start: -200d)
                                |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
                                |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "test_result")
                                |> filter(fn: (r) => r.version == ver)
                                |> keep(columns: ["_time", "test", "run", "status_tag", "duration_sec", "version"])'''

df = query_api.query_data_frame(query=query, params=params)
```

Running the above gives me a `HTTP response body: b'{"error":"type error 5:75-5:78: undefined identifier \\"ver\\""}\n'` error.

Does anyone know how to inject params correctly into a flux query with Python?

I also used the following for help:
https://influxdb-client.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/

### Update based on user16442705 question

I tried another variable name within my dict, and it yielded the same result. I also tried using $ in the query which yielded a different error. See the below code with errors:

```py
client = InfluxDBClient(url="localhost:5000", token="", timeout=100000, retries=0, enable_gzip=True, profilers="query, operator")
query_api = client.query_api()

ver = "data" # This variable would actually come from a function
params = {
    "pVersion": ver,
}
query =                      '''from(bucket: "db")
                                |> range(start: -200d)
                                |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
                                |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "test_result")
                                |> filter(fn: (r) => r.version == pVersion)
                                |> keep(columns: ["_time", "test", "run", "status_tag", "duration_sec", "version"])'''

df = query_api.query_data_frame(query=query, params=params)
```

`HTTP response body: b'{"error":"type error 5:67-5:80: undefined identifier \\"pVersion\\""}\n'`

```py
client = InfluxDBClient(url="localhost:5000", token="", timeout=100000, retries=0, enable_gzip=True, profilers="query, operator")
query_api = client.query_api()

ver = "data" # This variable would actually come from a function
params = {
    "pVersion": ver,
}
query =                      '''from(bucket: "db")
                                |> range(start: -200d)
                                |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
                                |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "test_result")
                                |> filter(fn: (r) => r.version == $pVersion)
                                |> keep(columns: ["_time", "test", "run", "status_tag", "duration_sec", "version"])'''

df = query_api.query_data_frame(query=query, params=params)
```

`HTTP response body: b'{"error":"loc 0:0-0:0: expected an operator between two expressions"}\n'`

Another data point to note is that we are using the following versions:

- Influxdb-Version: 1.8.6
- influxdb-client: 1.19.0

Comment: Does it work if you pass a hardcoded string like `"foo"` instead of `$pVersion`?  If so, it's a different problem.

Comment: Yes, if I pass the string inline it works. It also works if I pass the variable inline with `f'{pVersion}'`

Comment: Maybe you need to prefix your param names with `_`? From the example [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/pull/220#issue-607502337).

Comment: @user16442705 also not working for me...

Comment: Hmm, I'm stumped.  Could there be a version mismatch or something like that?  [This](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/pull/220#issue-607502337) seems just like what you're doing.

Comment: I agree, I have opened a bug on Influxdb-client, https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/issues/285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually with the version of influxdb I was using (1.8.6). The query params is not a feature of Influxdb 1.8.6, and was only introduced into Influxdb 2.0.x

See the link below for a question opened with the Influxdb-python-client team.
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/issues/285

Answer (score 1):

It appears that parameterized queries are only supported by Influx v2 Cloud. I've been fighting some similar issues in Golang for a bit and found that my local instance of Influx does not support it. Slightly frustrating that it is only a Cloud feature.

[Influx blog post about parameterized queries](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/tldr-influxdb-tech-tips-parameterized-flux-queries-with-influxdb/) Third sentence first paragraph states it is a Influx Cloud feature

[Influx Cloud documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/)
vs
[Influx V2 OSS documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.4/query-data/) Notice that there is no documentation for parameterized queries at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$ver` in your query string, instead of `ver`.

```
client = InfluxDBClient(url="localhost:5000", token="", timeout=100000, retries=0, enable_gzip=True, profilers="query, operator")
query_api = client.query_api()

ver = "data" # This variable would actually come from a function
params = {
    "ver": ver,
}
query = '''from(bucket: "db")
           |> range(start: -200d)
           |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
           |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "test_result")
           |> filter(fn: (r) => r.version == $ver)  # <--------------------------------- 
           |> keep(columns: ["_time", "test", "run", "status_tag", "duration_sec", "version"])'''

df = query_api.query_data_frame(query=query, params=params)
```

[Disclaimer](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/issues/701#issuecomment-484106755)

Comment: Oh, I see that you tried this already @RyanBurch.  I'll keep investigating.

Comment: Please see the above updates to my question.